# how to vectorize an operation on a 1 dimensionsal array to produce 2 dimensional matrix in numpy

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have a 1d array of values

```
i = np.arange(0,7,1)
```

and a function

```
# Returns a column matrix
def fn(i):
    return np.matrix([[i*2,i*3]]).T


fnv = np.vectorize(fn)
```

then writing

```
fnv(i)
```

gives me an error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", 
        line 1872, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", 
        line 1942, in _vectorize_call
        copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
  ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The result I am looking for is a matrix with two rows and as many columns as in the input array. What is the best notation in numpy to achieve this?

For example *i* would equal

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and the output would equal

```
[[2,4,6,8,10,12],
 [3,6,9,12,15,18]]
```

Comment: you shouldn't  use 'input' as a variable name, also could you show an example of the expected output?

Comment: Added an example output just to show the structure. The values are irrelevant and could be replaced by any values calculated within fn

Comment: Your function and your output do not match...

Comment: Yes it does.  f(1) -> [2,3]'  f(2) -> [4,6]'  etc

Comment: IS this so complex? Generate a sequence of columns and concat them together in the fastest way possible to make a matrix

Comment: the function you'r trying to vectorize is returning the wrong output

Comment: What is wrong about it? My answer correctly ( below ) correctly concats them into a matrix with 2 rows and n columns

Comment: @Jamie says vectorize is slow. At the moment I don't care about speed. Just want it to work.

Comment: though good tip about the ufuncs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**
You should try to avoid using `vectorize`, because it gives the illusion of numpy efficiency, but inside it's all python loops.

If you really have to deal with user supplied functions that take `int`s and return a `matrix` of shape `(2, 1)` then there probably isn't much you can do. But that seems like a really weird use case. If you can replace that with a list of functions that take an `int` and return an `int`, and that use `ufuncs` when needed, i.e. `np.sin` instead of `math.sin`, you can do the following

```
def vectorize2(funcs) :
    def fnv(arr) :
        return np.vstack([f(arr) for f in funcs])
    return fnv

f2 = vectorize2((lambda x : 2 * x, lambda x : 3 * x))

>>> f2(np.arange(10))
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]])
```

Just for your reference, I have timed this vectorization against your proposed one:

```
f = vectorize(fn)


>>> timeit.timeit('f(np.arange(10))', 'from __main__ import np, f', number=1000)
0.28073329263679625
>>> timeit.timeit('f2(np.arange(10))', 'from __main__ import np, f2', number=1000)
0.023139129945661807


>>> timeit.timeit('f(np.arange(10000))', 'from __main__ import np, f', number=10)
2.3620706288432984
>>> timeit.timeit('f2(np.arange(10000))', 'from __main__ import np, f2', number=10)
0.002757072593169596
```

So there is an order of magnitude in speed even for small arrays, that grows to a x1000 speed up, available almost for free, for larger arrays.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Don't use `vectorize` unless there is no way around it, it's slow. See the following examples

```
>>> a = np.array(range(7))
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.vstack((a, a+1))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
>>> np.vstack((a, a**2))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36]])
```

Whatever your function is, if it can be constructed with numpy's ufuncs, you can do something like `np.vstack((a, f(a)))` and get what you want

Comment: No that is just a degenerate example to show the principle. The tranformation within fn could be anything but output as a (2,1) column matrix

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Redid it completely, the basic idea still holds

Comment: Still no good. f(a) returns a column each of which should be concatenated to form an (2,N) matrix. fn could be *anything*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of ufuncs. As an old Matlab hack I should know to look for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A simple reimplementation of vectorize gives me what I want

```
def vectorize( fn):
    def do_it (array):
        return np.column_stack((fn(p) for p in array))
    return do_it
```

If this is not performant or there is a better way then let me know.